# Slow serial transfer from Java to Arduino

Tags: java, arduino

I have bidirectional communication between Java and Arduino, but am finding that when sending data from Java to Arduino it takes about 3.5 seconds to show up in the sketch.

Data sent from Arduino to Java has no such latency.

Any idea why this is the case?

Arduino code.
Here's my main loop,

```
void loop() {
  connection.sendData(systemVariables);
  connection.receiveData(systemVariables);
  world(systemVariables, ctr++);
}
```

Here's the sender,

```
 void  sendData(SystemVariables &sv) {
      String msg = String(sv.getReference());
      String pstr = String(sv.getPosition(), 2);
      msg = msg + "," ;
      msg = msg + pstr;
      msg = msg + "," ;
      msg = msg + sv.getOutput();
      Serial.println(msg);
    }
```

Here's the receiver,

```
 float receiveData(SystemVariables &sv) {

            String str;

            while (Serial.available() > 0) {
              str = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
              Serial.print('>');
              Serial.println(str);
            }
            if (str.length() > 0)
              sv.setOutput( str.toFloat());

      return sv.getOutput();
    }
```

Java 
The Java loop has a 25ms delay.

receiver

```
 public synchronized void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent oEvent) {
        //System.out.println("ET " + oEvent.getEventType());
        if (oEvent.getEventType() == SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE) {
            String inputLine = null;
            try {
                inputLine = input.readLine();
                if (inputLine.length() > 0) {
                    logger.log(Level.INFO, "{0}", inputLine);
                    if (!inputLine.startsWith(">")) {
                        String[] arr = inputLine.split(",");
                        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

                            try {
                                float newf = Float.parseFloat(arr[i]);
                                try {
                                    if (data.size() <= i) {
                                        data.add(newf);
                                    } else {
                                        data.set(i, newf);
                                    }

                                } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                                    logger.warning(e.toString());
                                }
                            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                                logger.log(Level.WARNING, "{0} <{1}> <{2}>", new Object[]{e.toString(), inputLine, arr[i]});
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(SerialSensorSingleton.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.warning(e.toString() + " Data received " + inputLine == null ? "null" : "<" + inputLine + ">");
            }

        }
    }
```

Sender

```
 public void write(String s) throws IOException {
        logger.log(Level.INFO, ":{0}", s);
        output.write(s.getBytes());
        output.flush();
    }
```

Comment: Could it not just be the time required to process the information on the arduino and display in the sketch?

Comment: No, it's only a few milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this now. The problem was that I was trying to implement synchronous communication with asynchronous methodology.

That is, I was using SerialEvent listener, but this is only intended for one way communication. I was trying to use the port to send data back the other way, but it was being blocked by the queue of data that built up for a certain period.

I have changed the method calls to read and writes so that each end sends only one message and than waits for incoming data. In this way each end is synchronised, and it now works like a dream.